# What does it mean? "Who is pissed off?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> Empathy is a competency that allows you to read people.
>   Who is supporting whom? Who is pissed off, and who is coasting?

There are some meanings for [pissed off](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/piss-off) in Longman Dictionary:

- to annoy someone very much
- to go away – used especially to tell someone to go away
- used to say no or to refuse to do something

I think the third is correct but I am not sure.

So, Could you please help me?

The full text is here:

> So how do we fi x meetings so they are more enjoyable and produce more
>   positive feelings? Sure, invite the right people, create better
>   agendas, and be better prepared. Those are baseline fi xes. But if you
>   really want to improve how people work together at meetings, you’ll
>   need to rely on—and maybe develop—a couple of key emotional
>   intelligence competencies: empathy and emotional self-management. Why
>   empathy? Empathy is a competency that allows you to read people. Who
>   is supporting whom? **Who is pissed off, and who is coasting?** Where is
>   the resistance? This isn’t as easy as it seems. Sometimes, the
>   smartest resisters often look like supporters, but they’re not
>   supportive at all. They’re smart, sneaky idea killers. Carefully
>   reading people will also help you understand the major and often
>   hidden confl icts in the group.

https://hbrascend.org/topics/key-to-a-great-meeting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context (and almost any time you hear the phrase *pissed off*), it is the first definition: to annoy someone very much.

So, "who is *pissed off*" can be read as "who is *very annoyed by something or someone in the meeting*".

Answer (score 0):

It is suggesting some of the qustions you are able to answer if you have empathy. You can tell who is supporting whom; you can tell who is pissed off; you can tell who is just coasting.

Comment: You can tell which of the people in the meeting (if any) are currently pissed off, and which of the people in the meeting (if any) are just coasting.

Comment: This does notm answer the question as to the meaning of "pissed off". In fct it does little beyond repeating the question.

Comment: I misunderstood what was being requested: since the OP gave a dictionary definition for "pissed off", I didn't think that was what they were asking about. "Pissed off" means "very annoyed".